# How to create a multi-module maven project with spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven-3, spring-rest

I am really new to spring boot and maven. I have tried to create a multi-module spring boot project using maven. When I create that and tried to access my controller endpoint through the url it will display 404 error.

I have tried a lot to resolve this problem and searched in the online documents but I was failed. Can anybody help me to resolve this.

In my project there are two modules called demo and activityops.

the parent pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.multimodule</groupId>
<artifactId>multimodule</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<modules>
    <module>activityops</module>
    <module>demo</module>
</modules>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <start-class>com.example.DemoApplication</start-class>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


  </project>
```

---

pom.xml in the activityops module is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>multimodule</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.multimodule</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>activityops</artifactId>
```

pom.xml in the demo module is below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<parent>
    <artifactId>multimodule</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.multimodule</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>


</project>
```

---

My controller class is below

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class TestController {
private static org.slf4j.Logger LOGGER =     LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestController.class);

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces =  {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public User getSingleUser() {

        User user = new User();
        user.setId(11l);
        user.setFirstName("Shane");
        user.setLastName("John");
        return user;
    }
}
```

---

I have typed the following url to access the controller method.
    http://localhost:8080/user

This will display and 404 error. Can anybody please help me to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: there's nothing in your question that is really related to the fact you app is a multi-modules project. If you want a quick and effective answer, the easiest is to share the project (on github for instance) and provide the link.

Comment: Hi Stephane I have added the project into git hub and you can access it through the below link. Thanks for your support....! https://github.com/dilan99x/mutimodule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is quite a lot going on in your project right now but the biggest problem is that your `demo` project has *no dependency on the other module*.

Also, that module defines your controller in the root package (don't do that!). Your Spring Boot application is located in `com.example`. By default, Spring Boot will scan the package where your Spring Boot application is located and all its sub-packages. `TestController` is not in `com.example` so it's not found. That's why you get a 404.

There were other issues, I have [submitted a pull request](https://github.com/dilan99x/mutimodule/pull/1) that demonstrates what you can do to make this sample project works. Check the commit message for more details.

Comment: Hi Stéphane I got an issue while running this application using mvn spring-boot:run command. Then it displays the java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.DemoApplication exception. I have tried to resolve this by my self and still I am unable to make it. Can you please tell me how can I resolve this problem...